# Folder _data in theme directory does not get the values

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm making a Jekyll theme using the command `jekyll new-theme mytheme`. I want to add translations to this theme, so I created the file `_data/translations.yml` into the root directory. This is its content:

```
---
en:
  post: "Post"
es:
  post: "Artículo"
```

I get the information with this expressions:

```
{% assign t = site.data.translations %}
{{ t[site.lang]['post'] }}
```

This setup only works if I move the `_data/translations.yml` file to my Jekyll website directory, created through the command `jekyll new mysite`.

Are the data files out of themes territory? Should I place this yml file in another directory? If it's not possible to use it in the themes territory, I would like to set a default value: how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Jekyll 4.0, yes, data files inside a theme-gem are not read.
You'll need to use a plugin named [`jekyll-data`](https://github.com/ashmaroli/jekyll-data) (authored by me).

If you plan to publish the theme for other users, I recommend adding the plugin as a runtime dependency in the theme's gemspec. Otherwise, simply adding the plugin to the `:jekyll_plugins` group in the site's Gemfile will suffice.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly the answer I needed. I will publish  this theme on RubyGems, so yes, I will add your plugin as a runtime dependency in the theme's gemspec.

Comment: BTW, @ashmaroli, is happening the same with pages? If I want to add the 404.md to the theme-gem, it's not getting the page.

Comment: Jekyll won't load *pages* from within a theme-gem. The best solution is to fashion an `error.html` layout and ask your users to use that layout for their 404 and other error pages at source.